# FreeIPA AD Trust based Integration using SunLDAP to store Policies

Tags: linux, active-directory, kerberos, sssd, freeipa

If we want to use the FreeIPA Active Directory Trust Integration Option, can we use an existing implementation of SunLDAP to store the Policies (e.g. sudo, hbac etc.)

Essentially we don't to create another LDAP Directory just for storing the Policies.

Comment: The purpose of the IPA/AD trust is to store user accounts in AD, and policy in IPA. If you don't want policy in IPA, what do you want IPA to do?

Comment: Hi Andy, we do want IPA to maintain the policies, but just want to use SunLDAP instead of 389 Directory Server for storing the policies. AD would be System of Records for the User Accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible as Alexander explained on freeipa-users: http://www.redhat.com/archives/freeipa-users/2016-June/msg00294.html

Comment: I guess my question is why it can't be done. Both 389DS and SunLDAP are LDAP complaint. So it should be possible. Right?

Comment: FreeIPA has a ton of plugins that only work with 389DS and IPA depends on them.